# Save line if exact number matches in the first column with awk/sed

Tags: awk, sed, grep

so my input is as following:

```
1,somerandomwordsx,some.random.words,random.numbers.word,random
2,somerandoms,random,randomnumber,
1,randomwords,word1,word2,word3
21,randomwords,words.random,unique.word,more.random.words
111,randomword1,random.word2
```

Output should be

```
1,somerandomwordsx,some.random.words,random.numbers.word,random
1,randomwords,word1,word2,word3
```

I tried many ways with awk, grep, sed, but either it ignores commas or it includes every "1," match, including "111," which it should not, only the line with the exact number 1 in the first column should be saved.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F , '$1 == 1' file
1,somerandomwordsx,some.random.words,random.numbers.word,random
1,randomwords,word1,word2,word3
```

With `awk` we may read each line as a set of fields delimited by commas.  The code above prints all lines where the first field (`$1`) is exactly `1`.

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed '/^1,/!d' file
1,somerandomwordsx,some.random.words,random.numbers.word,random
1,randomwords,word1,word2,word3
```

```
$ sed -n '/^1,/p' file
1,somerandomwordsx,some.random.words,random.numbers.word,random
1,randomwords,word1,word2,word3
```

Using `grep`:

```
$ grep '^1,' file
1,somerandomwordsx,some.random.words,random.numbers.word,random
1,randomwords,word1,word2,word3
```

With `sed` and `grep` we may use the regular expression `^1,` which means "the character `1` at at start of the line, followed by a comma".  The `^` anchors the expression to the start of the line, and by matching a comma after the `1` we avoid matching lines that start with `11` or `12` etc.

The first `sed` variation removes all lines that does not match this pattern while the other prints only lines that matches the pattern.  The effect is the same.

Comment: Oh man, thanks for confirming that these are the actual options which I tried all and that didnt work. And guess what, it didn't work as well and then I figured out, the file format is bugged, all lines were actually only one single line. So, I fixed the file format and everything works now. Thanks a lot!